# trying to create Global Variables in Node-red Getting an "Error: Callback must be a function"

Tags: node-red

```
// Code added here will be run once
// whenever the node is started.
if (global.get("GlobalFlag") !== undefined)  
{  
   node.warn("Globals exist");  
}  
else  
{  
 global.set("FullAuto_Zone1_Runtime", "FullAuto_Zone2_Runtime",
           "FullAuto_Zone3_Runtime","FullAuto_Zone4_Runtime");
}
```

// This is in a function node kicked off using the Startup trigger

// I tried putting the code in the Setup Tab and the On Start tab of the function Node with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for the  `global.set()` function is wrong, you have passed 3 strings, so it's interpreting the fist as the key (which wouldn't match `GlobalFlag` you tested for, the second string as the value, and the 3rd would be treated as a callback function for when the set if complete.

I assume you want to set `GlobalFlag` to an array of values, so the code should be:

```
// Code added here will be run once
// whenever the node is started.
if (global.get("GlobalFlag") !== undefined)  
{  
   node.warn("Globals exist");  
}  
else  
{  
 global.set("GlobalFlag", ["FullAuto_Zone1_Runtime", "FullAuto_Zone2_Runtime",
           "FullAuto_Zone3_Runtime","FullAuto_Zone4_Runtime"]);
}
```

You can find the doc for working with context in function nodes [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#getset-multiple-values)